# How to run selenium test in ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to running selenium test cases that invoke the chromedrivers with ubuntu.

I am facing below issue

```
[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  Run 1: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-10-1-8-153', ip: '10.1.8.153', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1045-aws', java.version: '11.0.16'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55cc6f1882c3 <unknown>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue , I am using below test configurations

```
 public WebDriver beforeScenario() {
        if (cr.valueOnTheKey("Env").equals("PROD")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedrive");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setHeadless(true);
        // options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        // driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
        }
```

I am using below steps before running mvn clean test

```
        sh 'sudo apt-get update -y'
        sh 'sudo apt-get upgrade -y'
        sh 'sudo apt install xvfb -y'
        sh 'sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
        sh 'sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb || true'
        sh 'sudo apt-get install -f -y'
        sh 'sudo google-chrome -version'
        sh 'sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/google-chrome'
        sh 'sudo nohup /usr/bin/google-chrome &'
        sh 'sudo wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/105.0.5195.19/chromedriver_linux64.zip'
        sh 'sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip'
        sh 'sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedrive'
        sh 'sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/chromedrive'
        sh 'sudo nohup Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 & DISPLAY=:99 &'
```

Comment: Try not to use `sudo` for running chrome and xvfb

Comment: Getting same error after this.
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  Run 1: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)